# Android - i need advice for a layout like this

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to do something like this:

[image: http://postimage.org/image/p06lj1vdf/]

What layout should I use to do it the best way?
Some particular combination?
I was thinking to use a GridLayout, but I am not sure.
Perhaps a combination of LinearLayout (top) and Grid (for the buttons)?

Comment: How many buttons will there be? If it were me I'd probably just stick with Relative / LinearLayouts

Comment: There are only 4 buttons (like in the image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say a RelativeLayout at the top because you can use attributes like this for example:

```
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo"
```

That means you can add all of the content in relation to each other and not have to worry about mass padding on each side of each item.

I would then use a GridView for the bottom so that the buttons are all laid out perfectly identical.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a table layout so it scales correctly for different size screens.

Comment: LinearLayouts using `android:layout_weight` will scale correctly too.

Comment: Do you think that i can do everything with table layout or i need to combine two or more layout? (i'm not very expert)